# asp.net core - Access deserialized object in middleware before controller gets called

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a pretty default asp.net core web api (.net 7). My controllers web api methods are decorated with [HttpPost] and their parameters come from the request body with [FromBody] attribute. Everything works fine.

Many (not all) of the methods parameter types inherit from the same base class. Now instead of performing some shared code in every of the controllers methods, where the type of the parameter inherits from this base class, I would rather like to do it on one place only (DRY). It seems like the middleware pipeline is the place to go. But I also want to avoid deserializing the object twice for performance reasons.

My question here is: Can I access the deserialized object, that is given to the controller method in my own middleware before the controller method gets called?

Comment: If you take a look at [Action Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#action-filters) in the ASP.NET Core MVC documentation, that should give you some pointers into how you can inspect the result from Model Binding before the action method is executed.

Comment: instead of performing some shared code in every of the controllers methods--why not create a service,move the related codes into service and inject it into different controllers?

Comment: Because I still would need to call that service code from every controller. The option with the action filter seems to be fitting best. Thank you very much

Comment: This doesn’t sound like a good idea. Can you show an example of the code you would like to write? Maybe a shared  model would be better than what’s suggested above